# Create Orient DB Edges with a Variable Class Name

Tags: csv, etl, orientdb

I will assume, that

the two classes are A and B
A has Id1
B has Id2
the class of the edge is a column value from the CSV file
A and B instances are present in the DB
The AtoB.csv is like

AId,EdgeName,BId

a1,"Loves",b1

a2,"LivesWith",b2

a2,"WorksWith",b3

Then the following ETL config will do. I have question marks ????????? at the class for edge. What do I put here? How do I reference a column in the incoming CSV file for this value?

[image]

The result will be

(a1) ➡ Loves ➡ (b1)

(a2) ➡ LivesWith ➡ (b2)

(a2) ➡ WorksWith ➡(b3)

Answer (score 0):

This is supported from OrientDB v3.0.7 (you can get 3.0.7-SNAPSHOT from Maven):

```
"class": "${input.EdgeName}"
```

In the edge block, where "EdgeName" is the column name containing the edge class. The class must be created beforehand. You could browse the same file and create all the classes in the 1st pass.

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/orientechnologies/orientdb-community/3.0.7-SNAPSHOT/